# asp.net html leaving an active effect under Navigation

Tags: jquery, css

What I am trying to do is leave an an effect when a user clicks on a navigational tab that indicates that they are in that tab.

I am still fairly new to JQuery so this might be wrong.

Javascript/JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu").find("a").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
        })
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.highlight
{
    text-decoration:none !important; 
    background-color: white;
    color: #999999;
    border-bottom: thick outset White;   
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
    text-decoration:none !important; 
}

div.menu ul li a
{
    color: #999999;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 13.6px;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration:none !important; 
}
```

Menu Code:

```
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu " EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/The_Team.aspx" Text="The Team"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Advisory_Board.aspx" Text="Advisory Board"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" Text="Contact"  />
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
```

Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ...

```
 $("#menu")
```

you need to use

```
  $(".menu")
```

for css class.

Comment: @user1552636 : yes you are trying to find an `a` tag inside menu which is not present

Comment: When asp.net c# builds it creates a tags inside the li. Microsoft generates a tags.

Comment: It looks like this:
<li class="static" role="menuitem" style="position: relative; float: left;">
<a class="level1 static" href="Default.aspx" tabindex="-1">Home</a>
</li>

Comment: @user1552636 : your question isnt clear isnt some thing not working ? can you to be more specific about your problem :)

Comment: I am trying to create a border line on the bottom after an onclick event. So it leaves a feeling that you know what page you are on. It's very popular for websites but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: http://www.brandammo.co.uk/blog/category/integrated/ on this site when you click tabs it leaves a mark on which tab you are in. In this case it circles a blue background on it.

Comment: Problem found using asp:menu causes issue since it uses server side menu. Fix is simple use normal menu.

Comment: glad to hear that ,If you wan to find your menuID on client side you can use ` $("#<%= NavigationMenu.ClientID %>")`..to find your `asp:menu` control